AWS Identity Center and SAML Response issue
I want to log in to my website through the AWS Access Portal and use the credentials (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SESSION_TOKEN) to access AWS services. Here's the process I tried:

Open the AWS Access Portal.
Navigate to the Applications tab.
Click on my application.
The portal sends a SAMLResponse to my website.
My website validates the SAMLResponse by making a request to AWS Identity Center.
Using SAML, assume a role and obtain AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, and AWS_SESSION_TOKEN.

I’m not sure if this flow works as intended. I encountered an issue at Step 4. I couldn’t figure out how it works.
Here’s what I tested for Step 4, following this reference on SAML 2.0 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0#SP_POST_Request;_IdP_POST_Response) :
I received the base64 encoded body from AWS, but when I try to POST the SAMLResponse to AWS SSO Assertion Endpoint, it returned "Bad Input", below it my request
curl --location 'https://portal.sso.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/saml/assertion/kgzMuN2MzZ3zAyGFhOWMTMzcyRg2OTQyjQMOTJj00X2l' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'SAMLResponse=PD94bWwgdmVy..............wvc2FtbDI6QXNzZvbnNlPg%3D%3D' \
--data-urlencode 'RelayState='

I got few question for this

Is this solution possible? If no, what is the best solution to obtain the credentials at within a webpage?

What is the correct format for the SAML Validation POST?

How to assume role from the SAMLResponse?


Edit 1:
This the XML decoded from SAMLResponse
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Destination="https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/default/test/acs" ID="_f9f0b1a3-81ea-42b1-8819-2921a4be5d95" IssueInstant="2024-11-26T14:41:15.575Z" Version="2.0">
    <Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">
        https://portal.sso.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/saml/assertion/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    </Issuer>
    <Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <Reference URI="#_f9f0b1a3-81ea-42b1-8819-2921a4be5d95">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <DigestValue>
                    8yrsz7cyrHzxryaa8k6UXvCxDV6CWtpfBz53DEaC7Ug=
                </DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>
            epZ0GLz0w3IscHjk5vqfgcWs1M9Evkie6JM0EJLnkCreiLE73fnu1uVwEQJl3S2kbLX uCHx2i2aQJPnpH0QLsG2EuDwWGtCZJGSOqGUyk4ijNdDakBAum6gYRxHwr1qQGDP9xMcTIvfQM+R Sl1cd18AvehLqPkKDAJqOsUpLIDvFMKYGYrv9uxTtxYDXOalcdNrmX7h7BVO2823f5Bf3of7wckQ RByG11Ku96NX1fFR/qSVA4+UtROGWunZBBkunA==
        </SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>
                    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
                </X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
    <Status>
        <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </Status>
    <Assertion ID="_9b22ee90-847b-44a4-8a05-b4177f40b8f7" IssueInstant="2024-11-26T14:41:15.575Z" Version="2.0">
        <Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">
            https://portal.sso.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/saml/assertion/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        </Issuer>
        <Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
                <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                <Reference URI="#_9b22ee90-847b-44a4-8a05-b4177f40b8f7">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                    <DigestValue>
                        Hiw8q/DdWWw5ltt9wlBbCalfIY=
                    </DigestValue>
                </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>
                r9YS5Go6s64NXjmHVQUpF4V8i4unXyP5goA+KU78g1mC8MY0vYkDEUsP0OLQHCzlevSPjv816ymU/Okx6m ulHSxK3vDhJwccQsCJeStokHadPZOGKsZ2xBfhdzT9BoN0lPi8hcHifaZKipsZ1rG1ofGj8liPOr BSXuD600KV/9a+uzPgwnabhIPW+wAtuiieJWhw==
            </SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
                <X509Data>
                    <X509Certificate>
                        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
                    </X509Certificate>
                </X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
        </Signature>
        <Subject>
            <NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" SPNameQualifier="https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/default/test/audience">
                xxxxxxx@xxxxx.com
            </NameID>
            <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2024-11-26T15:41:15.575Z" Recipient="https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/default/test/acs" />
            </SubjectConfirmation>
        </Subject>
        <Conditions NotBefore="2024-11-26T14:36:15.575Z" NotOnOrAfter="2024-11-26T15:41:15.575Z">
            <AudienceRestriction>
                <Audience>
                    https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/default/test/audience
                </Audience>
            </AudienceRestriction>
        </Conditions>
        <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2024-11-26T14:41:15.575Z" SessionIndex="_b7ef2ad4-c1cf-4765-b9e8-44e0d6b4d861" SessionNotOnOrAfter="2024-11-27T02:41:15.575Z">
            <AuthnContext>
                <AuthnContextClassRef>
                    urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport
                </AuthnContextClassRef>
            </AuthnContext>
        </AuthnStatement>
        <AttributeStatement />
    </Assertion>
</Response>


Interesting approach.  I can't answer most of your questions, but for "solution to obtain the credentials at within a webpage" you might want to look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithSAML.html

It sound like when I need, but I just not able to get the Credentials according to the Sample Request. Basically no idea how to generate the SAMLAssertion param from the SAMLReponse. AWS don't have any doc about it xml
